# Is the functor that assigns to an algebra its algebraic group of units fully faithful?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $A$ be a $d$-dimensional algebra over a field $K$. One can naturally assign to $A$ the linear algebraic $K$-group $\mathbf{GL_1}(A)$ that represents the functor $B \mapsto (A \otimes_K B)^\times$ for $K$-algebras $B$.
My question is:

> Is the functor $A \mapsto \mathbf{GL_1}(A)$ from finite-dimensional $K$-algebras to linear algebraic $K$-groups fully faithful, i.e. is the natural map
>   $$
> \hom_{K-\text{Alg}}(A,B) \to \hom_{K-\text{Grp}}(\mathbf{GL_1}(A), \mathbf{GL_1}(B))
> $$
>   for finite-dimensional $K$-algebras $A$ and $B$ a bijection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $K$-algebra $K$ doesn't have non-trivial endomorphisms as it is the inital object in $K-\text{Alg}$, but the linear algebraic $K$-group $\mathbf{GL_1}(K)$ does have non-trivial endomorphisms, for example $x \mapsto x^n$ for a fixed $n \in \Bbb N$, thus the functor is not full.

Comment: So the functor is not full, and consideration of $k[t]$ shows that it is not faithful either.